# What is the name of the song played during the scene where Asuna is buffing the party underwater in SAO Extra Edition?

Tags: music, sword-art-online

The song I'm referring to is often called the "Underwater quest BGM", as it is first played when Asuna is buffing the party in the Extra Edition. The next time it is played is in SAO II episode 2 near the ending.

Which album was the soundtrack placed in? Last time I checked, it wasn't in Volume 1 nor 2 of SAO II's OST.

Comment: Please take a look at the revision to see whether I changed the meaning of your post. Not sure what you mean by "Season's OST"

Comment: @nhahtdh You are fine there.

Comment: I do not think the song has been listed as of this moment it was not include in the 2nd ost volume or any of the extra music offered on discs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That song's real name is 'Moon and shadow' and is the 19th song of disc 4 of 'Sword Art Online Music Collection' (ソードアート・オンライン ミュージックコレクション)
which was released on 2016.01.27 (Catalog Number SVWC-70116~9).

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid you're out of luck for now. The [musical piece](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1fu0A2Vpxic) has not been released on any official soundtrack of Sword Art Online. It may be included in a package to be released in the future (but I haven't found any statements from the producers to this effect).